# Currency conversion and Purchase Power Data

Tags: currency

Where can I find multipliers to convert a certain amount in a currency, say USD of 1960 to say present EUR taking account of purchase power parity ?

Comment: EUR has different PP in different EU countries, so please be more specific?
A US dollar also has different PP in different countries but I assume you mean US PP.

Comment: Thanks for your pertinent comment as I'm not a specialist. Let's say Italy for example... but I was hoping to find data that would permit the conversion from many currencies and many dates !

Comment: Not to mention the USD has different purchasing power in different counties of the USA. How much is a cup of coffee in New York, California, North Dakota and Georgia?

Comment: @Dale M Consumer Price Index takes care of your remark by averaging the prices... Or, if you reread my question there could be multipliers for different counties.